# Can my telegram bot interact with a specific user (python)?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a bot with the purpose of annoying a friend of mine in Telegram. I would like it to reply only to him.

ex:

- friend: "hey"
- bot: "shut up"
- other person: "lol"
- friend: "lol"
- bot: "shut up"

is there a way in which i can specify such a restriction?

Comment: certainly since there has to be an identifier somewhere to identify the person, I don't know much about Telegram but if it has a web version the html could contain some identifier as to who is the person

Comment: It is possible to use the id, but I can't figure out how to use it as a filter

Comment: me neither, maybe like `if id == 'friend name':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used the corresponding tag, I'll assume that you use the `python-telegram-bot` library. In this case, there is [Filters.user](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.user) that you can use in combination with [MessageHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html) to only reply to one specific user:

```py
dispatcher.add_handler(
    MessageHandler(
        Filters.user(your_friends_user_id),
        lambda update, _: update.effective_message.reply_text('Shut up!')
    )
)
```